# use lookahead to match a string that starts and ends with a quotes and strip the quotes?

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to match on strings that start and end with the same quote, but only with the quotes at the start and end:

```
"foo bar"
'foo bar'
"the quick brown fox"
```

But I don't want these matched or stripped:

```
foo "bar"
foo 'bar'
'foo bar"
"the lazy" dogs
```

I tried with this java regexp but it doesn't quite work for all the cases:

```
Pattern.compile("^\"|^'(.+)\"$|'$").matcher(quotedString).replaceAll("");
```

I think there is a way to do lookahead, but I don't know how to use it in this case.

Or would it be more efficient to set up an if statement that checks them separately?

```
Pattern startPattern = Pattern.compile("^\"|^');
Pattern endPattern = Pattern.compile(\"$|'$");

if (startPattern.matcher(s).find() && endPattern.matcher(s).find()) {
    ...
}
```

(of course, this would match `'foo bar"`, which I do not want)

Comment: Are you saying that you want to strip single or double quotes when they surround two or more words, separated by whitespace inside the quotes?

Comment: What if the string has a quote in the middle? (e.g. 'It's my brown fox')

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis - I'm not worried about that corner case, this has to do with commandline stuff, so that wouldn't be valid anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is

```
^(["'])(.*)\1$
```

with the replacement string being `"$2"`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([\"'])(.*)\\1$");
String output = pattern.matcher(input).replaceAll("$2");
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/3a5PET

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method that can check all your requirements:

```
public static boolean matches (final String str)
{
    boolean matches = false;

    // check for null string
    if (str == null) return false;

    if ((str.startsWith("\"") && str.endsWith("\"")) || 
        (str.startsWith("\'") && str.endsWith("\'")))
    {
        String strip = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);

        // make sure the stripped string does not have a quote
        if (strip.indexOf("\"") == -1 && strip.indexOf("\'") == -1)
        {
            matches = true;
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

**Test**:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Should Pass\n-----------");
    System.out.println(matches("\"foo bar\""));
    System.out.println(matches("\'foo bar\'"));
    System.out.println(matches("\"the quick brown fox\""));

    System.out.println("\nShould Fail\n-----------");
    System.out.println(matches("foo \"bar\""));
    System.out.println(matches("foo \'bar\'"));
    System.out.println(matches("'foo bar\""));
    System.out.println(matches("\"the lazy\" dogs"));

}
```

**Output**:

```
Should Pass
-----------
true
true
true

Should Fail
-----------
false
false
false
false
```